# Linq query leading to invalid column name SqlException

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

ASPNET MVC5 web app, Visual Studio 2015

The website is language localized, so I need to get localized Categories depending on culture parameter.

The `category_trans` table accounts for providing category name translations while the `ISO_Languages` accounts for receiving a culture code parameter and passing its relating id the `category_trans`.

Models:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual category_trans category_trans { get; set; }
}

public partial class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class category_trans
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int language_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class ISO_Languages
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public string name_en { get; set; }
    public string name_fr { get; set; }
    public string name_it { get; set; }
    public string name_de { get; set; }
    public string name_es { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<Product> ActiveProductsPerUser(BaseContext db, string userid, string culture)
    {
        return from p in db.Products
               from ct in db.category_trans
               from l in db.ISO_Languages
               where (ct.category_id == p.CategoryID
               && ct.language_id == l.ID
               && l.code.Substring(0, 2) == culture)
               select p;
    }
```

results in an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'category_trans_category_id'. Invalid column name 'category_trans_language_id'. in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__174_0(Task`1 result)
>
>   in System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>   in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Please also note I am passing the expected result to another method for sorting and paging, thus accepting an `IQueryable` as input (no `IEnumerable`).

Comment: Code first or database first?

Comment: Hello. Code first.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
public static IQueryable<Product> ActiveProductsPerUser(BaseContext db, string userid, string culture)
    {
        var query = (from p in db.Products
                     join ct in db.category_trans
                     on p.CategoryID equals ct.category_id
                     join l in db.ISO_Languages
                     on ct.language_id equals l.ID
                     where l.code.Substring(0, 2) == culture)
                     select p).ToList();

        return query;
    }
```

Comment: The error was being caused by the recently added property "public virtual category_trans category_trans { get; set; }" in Product model class. I do not understand why. In any case I still need to retrieve category localized name together with products. I supposed that was the better way to do it but it does not work.

Comment: I have other virtual properties in Product model (public virtual Category Category { get; set; } and public virtual AspNetUsers User { get; set; } for instance) and they do not cause any problems. The only difference I can notice with virtual category_trans is that it has a composite PK (as shown in the model). May it be the error cause?

Comment: yes you have to write public virtual category_trans instead of virtual category_trans.