# Use Composite Primary key as Foreign key in EF

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

ASPNET MVC5 web application.

Model

```
 public partial class Product
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUsers User { get; set; }
```

I need to modify this model (working since ever) by including a new virtual property.

```
public virtual category_trans CategoryTrans { get; set; }
```

based on model:

```
public class category_trans
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int language_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Please note this table has a composite PK. This is the only apparent difference with the other virtual categories successfully implemented in Product model class up to now.

category_trans model class works just fine in many queries as defined but, as I introduce the new virtual CategoryTrans in Product model, **without even referencing it in any query**, i get following error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'category_trans_category_id'. Invalid column name 'category_trans_language_id'. in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__174_0(Task`1 result) in System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke() in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Comment: I would have expected the CategoryTrans as a property of Category class and not Product. That would make sense to me

Comment: @Sir Rufo: That sounds an interesting suggestion. I will try and elaborate on it.

Comment: Same EntityCommandExecutionException while creating CategoryTrans as a property of Category class. Must have something to do with CategoryTrans's composite PK.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `Product` Model as follows :

```
     public partial class Product{

    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryTrans"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Cat_ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryTrans"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Lang_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUsers User { get; set; }

    public virtual category_trans CategoryTrans { get; set; }
   }
```

This will work..

**EDIT**

T_SQL script of the created table given below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products] (
[Cat_ID]  INT            NOT NULL,
[Lang_ID]  INT            NOT NULL,
[ID]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Description] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[IsDeleted]   BIT            NOT NULL,
[IsApproved]  BIT            NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Products_dbo.category_trans_Cat_ID_Lang_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([Cat_ID], [Lang_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[category_trans] ([category_id], [language_id]) ON DELETE CASCADE);




GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Cat_ID_Lang_ID]
ON [dbo].[Products]([Cat_ID] ASC, [Langu_ID] ASC);
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'CategoryID' on type 'xxx.Models.Product' is not valid. The navigation property 'CategoryTrans ' was not found on the dependent type 'DumpZero.Models.Product'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

Comment: my Bad.. there was a space in "CategoryTrans".. In case you copied the same as my code.. u can try now..@Luke

Comment: You are right, but the error is now (quite obviously) about the LanguageID not being a valid column in Product Table. As a matter of fact both FK are not related to Product table.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CategoryTrans] (
    [category_id] INT           NOT NULL,
    [language_id] INT           NOT NULL,
    [name]        NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([category_id] ASC, [language_id] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([category_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Categories] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY ([language_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ISO_Languages] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: The reason why I need a reference to CategoryTrans in Product is because it accounts for category localization: CategoryTrans PK refer to Category and ISO_Languages. When I query for products I need to retrieve category translations altogether.

Comment: As i don't have access your entire code I dint notice that you have a `Category` model as well.. change the `CategoryID` property to something like `C_ID' and if you have a model  name `Language` you have to change `LocationID` property to something like `L_ID`.. and execute.. Its working .. I have already tested and updated the answer as well... Reason of the above error is EF by defaults will refer to `Category` Model  with the help of `CategroyID` Property @Luke

Comment: You can see it in my original post where Product model contains a : "public virtual Category Category { get; set; }". 

Here's the detail of the whole architecture: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085445/linq-query-leading-to-invalid-column-name-sqlexception".

I am afraid I do not understand your last suggestion.

Comment: no problem even if you don't understand.. you can go ahead and copy the answer and use.. its tested... :)

Comment: Sorry, no way I can modify a table that's in production since months. This model is being referenced by tens of methods. I can ADD something but change anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144773/discussion-between-abi-and-luke).

Answer (score 0):

The translation for the categories belong to the category itself and not to the product. So I recommend to add that to the category.

Model classes

```
public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CategoryTrans> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryTrans
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Definition of the relation with FluentAPI

```
public class Model1 : DbContext
{

    public Model1()
        : base( "name=Model1" )
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );

        var language = modelBuilder.Entity<Language>();
        language.HasKey( e => e.Id );
        language.Property( e => e.Name ).IsRequired().HasMaxLength( 100 );

        var product = modelBuilder.Entity<Product>();

        product.HasKey( e => e.Id );
        product.Property( e => e.Name ).IsRequired().HasMaxLength( 100 );
        product.Property( e => e.Description ).IsOptional().HasMaxLength( 1000 );
        product.Property( e => e.IsDeleted ).IsRequired();
        product.Property( e => e.IsApproved ).IsRequired();
        product.HasRequired( e => e.Category )
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey( e => e.CategoryId )
            .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );

        var category = modelBuilder.Entity<Category>();

        category.HasKey( e => e.Id );
        category.Property( e => e.Name ).IsRequired().HasMaxLength( 100 );
        category.HasMany( e => e.Translations )
            .WithRequired( e => e.Category )
            .HasForeignKey( e => e.CategoryId )
            .WillCascadeOnDelete( true );

        var categoryTrans = modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryTrans>();
        // composite key
        categoryTrans.HasKey( e => new { e.CategoryId, e.LanguageId } );
        categoryTrans.HasRequired( e => e.Language )
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey( e => e.LanguageId )
            .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );

    }
}
```

And the resulting migration

```
public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Languages",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Products",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    Description = c.String(maxLength: 1000),
                    IsDeleted = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    IsApproved = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    CategoryId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Categories", t => t.CategoryId)
            .Index(t => t.CategoryId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Categories",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.CategoryTrans",
            c => new
                {
                    CategoryId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    LanguageId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.CategoryId, t.LanguageId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Languages", t => t.LanguageId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Categories", t => t.CategoryId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.CategoryId)
            .Index(t => t.LanguageId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Products", "CategoryId", "dbo.Categories");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.CategoryTrans", "CategoryId", "dbo.Categories");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.CategoryTrans", "LanguageId", "dbo.Languages");
        DropIndex("dbo.CategoryTrans", new[] { "LanguageId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.CategoryTrans", new[] { "CategoryId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Products", new[] { "CategoryId" });
        DropTable("dbo.CategoryTrans");
        DropTable("dbo.Categories");
        DropTable("dbo.Products");
        DropTable("dbo.Languages");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I've already solved with what i suppose my be called a "data annotation" alternative. That is defining FK relations this way: 
public class CategoryTrans
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int category_id { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int language_id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("category_id")]
        public virtual Category categoryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("language_id")]
        public virtual ISO_Languages languageId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

Comment: That is the same I defined with FluentApi, except the WillCascadeOnDelete( false ) that can be set only with FluentApi.